# show detected face from IplImage to UIImage (iphone opencv)

Tags: iphone, opencv, uiimage, face-detection, iplimage

I have a rectangle(x,y,width,height) represent a face in a image. The rectangle is got from opencv face detect algorithm. But I want to use a label to display in UIImage format.

The problem is the coordinate is got from IplImage, and has the wrong location in UIImage.

Comment: this is too vague, what is the correct expected coordinates? what do you get? are you simply missing an offeset? expand this with a simple example

Comment: @SamSaffron e.g. I get a rectangle with origin(230,10) and size(160,100). It bounds a face in iplimage format. Then when I transfer it to ui image format, I can't find the corresponding rectangle to bound the face. Thx

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle you got may be in userspace so change that to device space. Maybe this is your problem. If you want a better solution, please elaborate on the code so that somebody can actually help you.